# file not found when I trying to open it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to open the certificate file:

```
//path to file
static string KKBpfxFile = 
    Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath,
                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertFolder"], 
                 "cert.pfx");

_logger.Debug(KKBpfxFile);

X509Certificate2 KKbCert = new X509Certificate2(KKBpfxFile, KKBpfxPass);
```

But, I get exception file is not found. In the log file contais the following path:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\msite\Certificates\cert.pfx

I open this path in the Explorer and all it's ok. The file is exist.
Where is a problem?

PS. I gave all (read, write and other) permission to this folder to `ALL` group.
PS2. This is problem only on production server. On my local machine is works.

Comment: what's the method returns?

`Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertFolder"]`

maybe his return different path than  

`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\msite\Certificates\`

?

Comment: Where are you trying to open this file? Could you show the code of your controller action?

Comment: May be a stupid question, but have you made sure the app settings are all OK? If you know the file is there, and you get "File not found", then you are probably not looking for it in the correct place! ;)

Comment: Try to add explicit permissions (read, write and other) to this folder to "local system" and "network services" users

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I open file in `X509Certificate2 ...`

Comment: Could you show your controller action? Where is the code you have shown in your question located?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put a `File.Exists()` check before the call to the constructor.

Also there still might be an issue with access rights depending on what user the application pool is running on, but if you set access rights to "Everyone" it should work. Still...double-check that on the production server.

Also as a further step you could check the ACL of the file and see if you have read rights to it before calling the constructor and even further still, load the file into a byte array and call the constructor with the byte array as arg.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tryed convert to byte array. But result is the same

Comment: @user1260827 The same meaning that it fails when opening the file to read it to a byte[] ?

Answer (score 0):

use procexp.exe and give the path in the exe. I will say you which program has locked your file. Request the program to relase it.. Dont kill it as it is production server.

Procexp can be found in your local machine/downloaded from microsoft. copy tat exe to produciton server and run from there